# Log the beginning and the end of my methods

Tags: java

I log the beginning and the end of my methods like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething() {
        logger.debug(“doSomething is being called”);
        // do stuff
        logger.debug(“Finished calling doSomething”);
    }
}
```

Is there a library or a good way to automatically do this without having to explicitly write those lines to log?

Comment: `System.out.println`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/407637/2773311

Comment: How can you pass a custom message without calling a method?  You _could_ extend a superclass which does some logging, but this would only fire at the time `super()` is called.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732069/how-to-automatically-log-the-entry-exit-of-methods-in-java) could work?

Comment: @CalvinP. Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.