# Which logging framework could do line by line logging of the executed code in Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

Which logging framework supports the logging at every line of code in Spring Boot 2.x? So that I will get the detailed information of my code execution to track the issues.

In simple words I want to get detailed log of my code execution in Spring Boot 2.x. How can I achieve this?
I am using SL4J for AOP based logging now.

Thanks.

Comment: None. You will need a AOP to intercept the methods and do the logging. There is no logging framework that on its own provides this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732069/how-to-automatically-log-the-entry-exit-of-methods-in-java